# JTextArea Backspace and Clear

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextarea

I'm working on a calculator GUI, and I need help coding a backspace and clear button.

Below is the code, and `names[0][3]` is the backspace character, `names[0][4]` is to clear the entire area.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class CalcGUI extends JFrame
{   
    private Container contents;
    private final JPanel entryPanel, buttonPanel;
    private final JTextArea entryTA;
    private final JButton equalJB;
    private JButton [][] buttons;
    private final String [][] names =
    {{"7", "8", "9", "\u2190", "C"},
     {"4", "5", "6", "+", "-"},
     {"1", "2", "3", "*", "/"},
     {"0", ".", "(", ")", "^"}};

    public CalcGUI()
    {
        super("Calculator");

        contents = getContentPane();
        contents.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        buttons = new JButton [4][5];
        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 5));

        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton(names[i][j]);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(bh);
                buttonPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }

        contents.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        entryTA = new JTextArea(3, 1);
        entryTA.setLineWrap(true);
        entryPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        entryPanel.add(entryTA); 
        contents.add(entryPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        equalJB = new JButton("=");
        equalJB.addActionListener(bh);
        contents.add(equalJB, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)
        {  
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++)
                {
                    if (ae.getSource() == buttons[i][j])
                    {
                        if (ae.getSource() != buttons[0][3]
                            && ae.getSource() != buttons[0][4]) 
                        {
                            entryTA.append(names[i][j]);
                        }
                    } 
                    //backspace
                    else if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][3])
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            Document doc = entryTA.getDocument();
                            if (doc.getLength() > 0)
                            {
                                doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (BadLocationException ble) 
                        {
                            ble.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    //clear - works, as per @Frostsoft's solution
                    else if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][4])
                    {
                        entryTA.setText(""); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        CalcGUI calc = new CalcGUI();
    }
}
```

Any help or advice appreciated. Thanks!

edit: I think the problem is that it is backspacing until `doc.getLength > 0` is false. Removing the condition leads to an exception being thrown, however.

```
Document doc = entryTA.getDocument();
if (doc.getLength() > 0)
{
    System.out.println(doc.getLength());
    doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
    System.out.println("removed");
}
```

For input `789`, pressing backspace JButton only once:

```
3
removed
2
removed
1
removed
```

Comment: For better help, please show your attempt to use Document.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added it in the main post. I'm not sure if I implemented it correctly, but it always throws the exception.

Comment: Consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can experience your problem first hand.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Please see main post. I added the full code as it isn't too long, and this way people can run it as I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Document#remove` seems to work just for me...

The reason I'd prefer to use `Document#remove` in this case is because it doesn't create a bunch of temporary `String`, making more efficient but (ever so slightly) faster ;)

[image: backspace]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public Test1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 60);
                ta.setText("Bananas in pajamas are coming down the stairs,"
                                + "\n"
                                + "Bananas in pajamas are coming down in pairs,");

                JButton back = new JButton("Backspace");
                back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            Document doc = ta.getDocument();
                            if (doc.getLength() > 0) {
                                doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
                            }
                        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
                frame.add(back, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

**Updated**

The problem is with your loop...

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++) {
        //...
        else if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][3]) {
            try {
                Document doc = entryTA.getDocument();
                if (doc.getLength() > 0) {
                    doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
                }
            } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
                ble.printStackTrace();
            }
        } //clear - works, as per @Frostsoft's solution
        else if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][4]) {
            entryTA.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

On each iteration of the loop, when pressing the back space button, `else if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][3]) {` will be true..., the same holds true for `else if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][4]) {` when you press the clear button

Instead, remove the clear and backspace checks from the loop...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++) {
            if (ae.getSource() == buttons[i][j]) {
                if (ae.getSource() != buttons[0][3]
                                && ae.getSource() != buttons[0][4]) {
                    entryTA.append(names[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][3]) {
        try {
            Document doc = entryTA.getDocument();
            if (doc.getLength() > 0) {
                doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
            }
        } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
            ble.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (ae.getSource() == buttons[0][4]) {
        entryTA.setText("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to be away from the computer last night, but I've posted the full code in the main post, as it isn't that long. I tried your solution, and it doesn't throw an exception, but it just deletes everything for me.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the condition `doc.getLength() > 0`. It continues to remove characters until the condition is false.

Comment: @pez In my example, it's only an `if` condition, which can only be executed once per click...

Comment: I know, your standalone code runs fine. Can you take a look at my code above? Once I implement your code, it runs multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I would try doing `entryTA.setText("");` for clearing the TextArea and then use `entryTA.setText = (entryTA.getText()).substring(0, entryTA.getText().length()-1)` For removing the last char in the TextArea. That is just code off the top of my head but it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, your code for the clear was simple and worked. The backspace one isn't working. I tried `entryTA.setText(entryTA.getText().substring(0, entryTA.getText().length() - 1));` which I think should work, but it throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` I don't see why, since the `substring` starts at the first index 0 and ends at `length()-1`.

Comment: try debugging it by adding some sysout's returning the length of the string, so maybe you can see that the string is longer than you think. And then ajust the ...length()-whatever. Or maybe try doing length -2? just try different things and maybe post what the entire exception is returning?

Comment: I ran the program and entered `123` then hit the backspace button. I added `System.out.println("length: " + entryTA.getText().length());` to see what the length was, and it returned `length: 3` `length: 2` `length: 1` `length: 0`. This is why there was an exception, I suppose, but I'm not familiar enough with `JTextArea` to know why it does that.

Comment: you can also try this `entryTA.setText((entryTA.getText()).substring(0, entryTA.getText().length()-1));` idk if that will change it but its worth a shot.